# first jQuery tutorial not working

Tags: jquery

hi i try the first jQuery tutorial from jquery.com. i copied the code from there. the html link works, but the alert window with jquery does not work. 
what i tried so far:

- checked that javascript is enabled
- deleted old jquery files
- put the google jquery api as a source in the script-tag (instead the path to the jqueryfile)
- cried
- searched for synthax errors (typos can't be because i copied the code snippet)
- downloaded firebug
- tried the code with firefox and chrome

But nothing worked so far. thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">       </script>    
       <script>
     // your code here 
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
          alert( "Thanks for visiting!" );
         });
         });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Runs fine for me, exactly as you wrote it](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/rQmNJ/). What "does not work" about the alert window?

Comment: it just didn't appear, but putting http to the script source helped

Comment: I wonder if adding `http:` is necessary when running local files. It shouldn't be.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're script source is missing and http or https

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">       </script>    
       <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "a" ).click(function() {
              alert( "Thanks for visiting!" );
         });
         });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't resolve anything as there's nothing wrong with leaving it out and it's what Google tells you to do.

Comment: If that's the case, why does Google's own browser give the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined , however, when you qualify it with http or https, the error goes away? It sounds like it's not able to resolve the resource.

Comment: Where are you seeing "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" and the second part of your answer is also irrelevant as the extra spaces are fine.

Comment: Something else must be causing it, Google's own homepage uses the syntax and it's entirely correct

Comment: @PaulCalabro It's not that your code wouldn't work -- it certainly does. But so does the OP's code, so this doesn't really solve anything. And yes, suggesting to change `$( "a" )` to `$("a")` is just silly.

Comment: Indeed, actually suggestions like changing spacing would likely be confusing to people learning jQuery

Comment: I had thought the whitespace was causing the issue at first, I'll edit that part right now.

Comment: thank you! putting http: in front of the script source worked : )

Comment: If that worked for you, would you mind marking this as the solution? Thx :)